# Add black border to react icon

Tags: html, css, reactjs, icons

I have the following react icon AiFillHeart https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/search?q=heart

I would like it to have a red fill with a black border around the heart. What is the best way to go about this?

Is something like this feasible with this icon or should I switch to a different one (perhaps )?